# PowerShell doesn't like the -AssignDriveLetter option of the New-Partition cmdlet

Tags: powershell, partition, powershell-v3.0

I'm trying to create a partition on the USB flash drive using the `New-Partition` cmdlet. But when I use the `-AssignDriveLetter` option I get "New-Partition : Invalid Parameter" even though this option exists in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848714.aspx):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $disk = (Get-Partition -DriveLetter "F" | Get-Disk)    
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $disk

Number Friendly Name                            OperationalStatus                          Total Size Partition Style          
------ -------------                            -----------------                          ---------- ---------------          
4      UFD 2.0 Silicon-Power16G USB Device      Online                                       15.14 GB MBR                      

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $disk | Clear-Disk -RemoveData

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-Partition -DiskNumber $disk.Number -Size 350MB -AssignDriveLetter -IsActive
New-Partition : Invalid Parameter
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Partition -DiskNumber $disk.Number -Size 350MB -AssignDriveLetter -IsActive
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk) [New-Partition], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 5,New-Partition
```

Strangely, the partition is still created and some drive letter is assigned to it.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are all of you questions related to issues with the same USB flash drive?

Comment: Yes. But they are different questions, so I split them.

Comment: what is in your $disk variable?

Comment: @August I've already closed the console. What are you interested in? It's just a normal (flash) drive without partitions (after `Clear-Disk`).

Comment: How did you populate $disk?  What data is in that variable?  It seems to be an object based on the way you are using it ($disk.Number), but you don't say how you populated it in the first place or what data it contains. You can't just type "$disk" and get info out of it.

Comment: @August, $disk is `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk` which I got from the `Get-Disk` cmdlet. I've updated my question to indicate this.